# Запись байт в массив данных (C#)

Tags: c#, byte

Допустим есть массив данных, произошла какая-то математическая операция над этими байтами и нам надо сохранить результат в в другой массив, тоже состоящий из байт. Я делаю это в цикле.

```
public static byte[] bitData;
public static byte[] testData = { };

// Математические операции

for (int i = 0; i < bitData.Length; i++) {
 testData[i] = (byte)(bitData[i]);
}
```

При выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка: "Индекс находился вне границ массива." Подскажите, как решить данную проблему, чтобы появилась возможность записать эти результаты в виде байт в другую переменную. Спасибо!

Comment: Подумайте что делает строчка `byte[] testData = { };` и поймете в чем у вас ошибка

Comment: Если я убираю `= { };`, то появляется другая ошибка: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Иначе, как это представить правильно?

Comment: Я вас не прошу убрать, я прошу сказать что делает эта строчка

Comment: Я так полагаю, что инициализирует данную переменную, что бы не было абсолютно пустого значения.

Comment: Инициализирует. Каким значением?

Comment: Очевидно, что никаким, ведь оно пустое.

Comment: Очевидно, что ваше очевидно не верно. В C# нет такого понятия как никакое значение. Если вы не указываете значение для инициализации *поля класса*, то используется значение `null` для ссылочных типов (массив — это ссылочный тип). Вы же указываете значение для инициализации явно и что оно обозначает — смотрите в моем ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Массивы в C# не поддерживают изменение вместительности.

Строчку

```
byte[] testData = { };
```

компилятор разворачивает в

```
byte[] testData = new byte[0];
```

т. е. он создает массив вместительностью 0 элементов.

У вас есть, как минимум, 2 решения:

- можно создать массив нужной вместительности перед тем как заполнять его

  ```
  testData = new byte[bitData.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i < bitData.Length; i++) {
      testData[i] = bitData[i];
  }
  ```
- либо использовать готовую коллекцию, поддерживающую динамическое изменение вместительности

  ```
  var testData = new List<byte>();
  for (int i = 0; i < bitData.Length; i++) {
      testData.Add(bitData[i]);
  }
  ```

обратите внимание, что здесь используется метод `Add` который сначала увеличивает вместительность коллекции, а затем добавляет указанное значение последним элементом. Использование индексатора выбросит такое же исключение как и получаете вы.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам!

Comment: Как не поддерживают изменение вместительности?? А как же Array.Resize<T>?

Comment: @LiptonDev, лучше об этом не знать, кмк :)

Answer (score 0):

Для чего вы кастуете byte в byte (byte)(bitData[i]);?
По делу:
Для копирования данных из массива в массив используется (обычно) класс Array и метод Copy:

```
byte[] array = {1,2};
byte[] newArray = new byte[array.Length];

Array.Copy(array, newArray, array.Length);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но если я хочу над каждым элементом массива байт произвести математическую операцию, в последствии ее записать как массив байт, который является результатом.

Comment: так произведите с начальным массивом (в моем примере - array), затем его скопируете в новый, в чем проблема?